# How to set name for ejabberd muc service

Tags: ejabberd

I wish to set up a spare muc service on our non-primary ejabberd node so that users can continue to use muc in a limited fashion when our primary ejabberd node (which hosts the primary muc service) is down for maintenance.

Here is the configuration that I am using, which seems to work.

```
  {mod_muc,      [
                  {host, "spare_conference.@HOST@"},
                  {access, muc},
                  {access_create, muc},
                  {access_persistent, muc_admin},
                  {access_admin, muc_admin}
                 ]},
```

However, it shows up in service discovery with the same name as the other muc service: "Chatrooms".

The iq stanza from the server has:

```
identity category="conference" type="text" name="Chatrooms"
```

Is that "name" attribute configurable?  I don't see this in the ejabberd guide documentation.  How do I configure the muc service so that it shows a different name?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the the name without recompiling the code.  It's hardcoded in src/mod_muc/mod_muc.erl